# Форма регистрации Drupal 7

Tags: drupal

На сайте есть форма регистрации с инпутами и select и input-file, я бы хотел чтобы письма отправлялись на почту и сохранялись в админ панели, и после чтобы человек смог экспортировать данные в excel. Может быть есть готовые модули ? Если нет, то подскажите с чего нужно начать.

Answer (score 1):

Только самопис (модуль) с привлечением PHPExcel (https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel), например.